# Threejs - Best way to handle partial transforms on geometry vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have mesh with a geometry of about 5k vertices. This is the result of multiple geometries being merged so it's all in a flat array. So far all good, I can modify individual vertices and by setting the flag verticesNeedUpdate=true I can see the changes reflected on my mesh. My problem is that I need to make translations and rotations on some of this vertices and I was wondering if there is better way of applying transforms for each collection apart from modifying each vertex position inside a loop to apply the transforms.

One idea I had was to create a new geometry and assign the vertices subset (by reference) so I could then do the transforms but that seems weird so I stopped and ask this question instead.

I took a look at this example https://threejs.org/examples/?q=constr#webgl_buffergeometry_constructed_from_geometry but I have no idea how would I go about rotating/scaling groups of vertices.

Also from what I understand this will reduce the calls to the GPU by uploading only one set of vertices instead of having hundreds of calls. But then I wonder if modifying this geometry vertices on each frame defeats the all purpose of doing all this?

Answer (score 2):

As i can see, the example creates multiple heartshapes *(geometry)* and applies a transformation, then the transformed vertices are combined to one geometry *(bufferGeometry)*. So all hearts are in the same geometry and drawn in one call. The downside is, that you *can't* manipulate the heart individually.

The clue here is that the transformations are done initially and the transformed coords are uploaded to the gpu. You don't want to update the vertices each frame by the cpu.

```
geometry.lookAt( vector );
geometry.translate( vector.x, vector.y, vector.z );
```

is responsible for transforming the vertices, before they are added to the bufferGeometry.

---

If you can add an 'index' to each vertex, you could use a [UBO](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.7.16) for storing matrices and give vertices different transformations (in vertexshader) within the same drawcall.

Comment: I see. I guess I followed this approach because there are plenty of examples like [this one](http://vuoriov4.com/how-to-reduce-draw-calls-in-three-js) out there. I can totally see the performance benefits of doing all that at the vertex shader level. Is just that doing the matrices op's by hand seems daunting to me. Nevertheless, I'll give try and report back.